# How to exit from .loop in .batch file when it find at first time after replace it from .c file

Tags: batch-file

The code is used to search a string from .c file and replace it.The size of file is too long so I just want to exit the loop when it find the string and replace it.

```
@echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
cd D:\abc
set INTEXTFILE=rev.c
set OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt
set SEARCHTEXT=BNE1.9
set REPLACETEXT=BNE1.8
set OUTPUTLINE=

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"findstr /n ^^ %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
   SET string=%%A
   
   for /f "delims=: tokens=1,*" %%a in ("!string!") do set "string=%%b"
   if  "!string!" == "" (
       echo.>>%OUTTEXTFILE%
   ) else (
      SET modified=!string:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!
      echo.!modified! >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
      exit /b
  )
)
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

Answer (score 0):

As your code is reading each line one by one and writing it to a resulting file, then using your batch file methodology there is unfortunately no way to stop at the first replacement, without losing each line below that replaced string line.

To do that you would need to use a scripting language or utility which can edit files as opposed to read them bit by bit and rewrite them entirely. I strongly advise that you consider a find and replace utility, or perform this task using the built-in WSH or PowerShell scripting languages instead.

As a side note, this is how I might have tackled the script you posted, which may perform the task a little more speedily:

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

CD /D "D:\abc" 2>NUL || Exit /B

Set "INTEXTFILE=rev.c"
Set "OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt"
Set "SEARCHTEXT=BNE1.9"
Set "REPLACETEXT=BNE1.8"

If Not Exist "%INTEXTFILE%" Exit /B
Copy /Y "%INTEXTFILE%" "%OUTTEXTFILE%" 1>NUL

(
    For /F "Delims=" %%G In (
        '%SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /I /N /V "" 0^<"%OUTTEXTFILE%"'
    ) Do (
        Set "NumberedLine=%%G"
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Set NumberedLine | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "%SEARCHTEXT%" 1>NUL
        If Not ErrorLevel 1 (
            Set "NumberedLine=!NumberedLine:%SEARCHTEXT%=%REPLACETEXT%!"
        )
        Echo(!NumberedLine:*]=!
        EndLocal
    )
) 1>"%INTEXTFILE%"
Rem Del "%OUTTEXTFILE%"
```

***Feel free to remove the `Rem`ark on the last line, if you are sure you do not want a copy of the original file content.***

The main issue with your chosen method is that multiple joined delimiters are considered as only one. That means any line which began with a colon, `:`, that would be lost here `"delims=: tokens=1,*"`.
Additionally, this version opens the file for writing only once, whereas yours opened the file for writing, for each line, then closed it again before repeating for the next.